# How to permanently disable toggle button?

Tags: android, togglebutton

First I want to change the state of toggle button from false to true, then if its true I want to disable toggle button so no one can change it again.Please help me as I am new to android.

Comment: NO i can change it again if i want to, so its not the answer i am looking to.

Comment: see the answer i have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do like this,

```
    //get the button as
    ToggleButton tb =  (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton1);
    // check it is enabled
    if(tb.isChecked()){
        //do something on enabling it
        tb.setEnabled(false);  // disable it
    }
```